# Layout issues after updates to xcode 9

Tags: layout, xcode9

I've updated Xcode 8 to Xcode 9, and now .xib files on main screen not looking good.
Buttons and Labels not fit in screen and looks like it was cut.

Someone familiar with those issues?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with multiline labels inside UIStackView. If you set label's amount of lines to anything other than 1, stack view goes crazy and layout looks totally broken in interface builder.

I've solved it by explicitly adding a constant width constraint to the label, but checked "remove at build time". So that it looks OK in interface builder but doesn't interfere with app's behavior.